# How to modify p4v commands

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to modify the command line commands that P4V executes? For example say I'd like `revert` to do

```
p4 revert -w <blah>
```

instead of

```
p4 revert <blah>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with bash as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/105375/bash-spaces-in-alias-name).

```
p4() {
    if [[ $@ == "revert" ]]; then
        command p4 -w $@
    else
        command p4 "$@"
    fi
}
```

Use like normal command

```
p4 revert file
```

Bash will use the function above instead and pass the -w flag if revert is given, but not otherwise.

To make the change permanent, but it in e.g. your `.bashrc` and log in/out.

Comment: I'm not sure that will affect what **P4V** does when you revert, though.

Comment: Exactly as Bryan's comment - This is for p4v on Windows

Comment: I see. I don't think there is an option for that in the P4V client though :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the custom tools feature in P4V to customize a command to use the flags that you want. If you have multiple commands, then put them in a script and call the script from the tool. See 'Configuring Custom Tools'
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/advanced_options.custom.html

For example, ere is how to setup output to show the size of a file/folder using P4V Custom Tools. (The setup is quick - likely less than 5 minutes.)

INSTRUCTIONS:

1) In P4V, Click on Tools -> Manage Custom Tools. Click the 'New'
     button and select 'Tool'.

2) Fill in the 'Name' field to identify the operation.
     For example:

```
     Show Sizes
```

3) Click the check-box for 'Add to applicable context menus'

4) In P4V, under 'Application', enter "p4"

```
     Application = p4
```

5) For the 'Arguments' enter the command and arguments:

```
     sizes -s %D

 The %D is for any selected file or folder in depot syntax.
```

6) In P4V: Click the check-box for 'Run tool in terminal window'.

7) Click the 'OK' button and save your changes.

Once the custom tool is setup as below, you can just right-click on a file/folder and at the bottom of the drop-down menu you can select 'Show Size' (or whatever you would like to name the tool feature). It will also appear at the bottom of the Tools menu. The results will come up in a window.

Comment: Thanks, I guess there's no way to modify the behavior of the stock `revert` context menu option then?

Comment: You can modify the revert command using the custom tool to use the flags that you want.